# Profile field for event not showing

Tags: profile

I have set up a profile for an event we are running but one of the fields is not appearing and I am not sure why. When I view the preview it is there but not showing on the booking page for the event. It is the Participant - Access Requirements field.  Any advice appreciated!

Comment: Have you double-checked that the permission "access all custom data" is On for end users?

Comment: How do I do this please?

Comment: Go to Administer/User and Permissions/Permissions (Access Control). The click on the top option Drupal/Wordpress/Joomla Access Control. Make sure anonymous users have "CiviCRM: access all custom data " checked

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SE! Presumably that is a custom field? Check in the settings of its Custom Group that the box "Is this Custom Data Set public?" is ticked.  (Go to `Administer > Customise Data and Screens > Custom Fields`, on the relevant Custom Group go to `More > Settings`)

Comment: Hi thank you I have checked this and it is ticked to be public.